# How to use format's iteration ability on a list of conses

Tags: format, common-lisp

I know that I can use `format`'s `~:{ ~}` operator to process a list of lists directly, e.g.

```
CL-USER> (format t "~:{<~A,~A> ~}~%" '((1 2) (3 4)))
<1,2> <3,4>
```

But now I have a list of conses, e.g. `((1 . 2) (3 . 4))` and the expression

```
(format t "~:{<~A,~A> ~}~%" '((1 . 2) (3 . 4)))
```

leads to SBCL complaining

```
The value
  2
is not of type
  LIST
```

Is there any `format` magic doing the trick without having to use an extra iteration with `do` or `loop`?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly _no_: you need to convert your lists to proper lists, `format` cannot handle dotted lists. I have no proper reference to the *no* answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see basically 4 options

#### Do not use format for the whole list

The straightforward solution is avoid the problem:

```
(loop 
  for (k . v) in '((1 . 2) (3 . 4))
  do (format t "<~a,~a> " k v))
```

#### Custom format function

Alternatively, use [Tilde Slash](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_ced.htm) to call a function that prints cons-cells:

```
(defun cl-user::pp-cons (stream cons colonp atsignp)
  (declare (ignore colonp atsignp))
  (format stream "~a, ~a" (car cons) (cdr cons)))

(format nil "~/pp-cons/" (cons 1 2))
=> "1, 2"
```

Note that the function must be in the CL-USER package if you don't specify the package. If you want to customize how cells are printed, you need to pass the format through a special variable:

```
(defvar *fmt* "(~s . ~s)")

(defun cl-user::pp-cons (stream cons colonp atsignp)
  (declare (ignore colonp atsignp))
  (format stream *fmt* (car cons) (cdr cons)))
```

And then:

```
(let ((*fmt* "< ~a | ~a >"))
  (format t "~/pp-cons/" (cons 1 2)))

=> < 1 | 2 >
```

#### Convert on printing

Build a fresh list, where improper lists are replaced by proper lists:

```
(format t
        "~:{<~a,~a> ~}~%"
        (series:collect 'list
          (series:mapping (((k v) (series:scan-alist '((1 . 2) (3 . 4)))))
            (list k v))))
```

The drawback is that the conversion needs to allocate memory, just for printing.

#### Change your data format

If proper lists are good for printing, maybe they are good for other operations too. A lot of standard functions expect proper lists. Note that the list `((1 2) (3 4))` is still an alist, the value is just wrapped in a cons-cell. If you decide to use this format from the start, you won't have to convert your lists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I think in the first place option 4 would have been the best but I will stick with the first one for now.